# Android Studio can't find Boost headers

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, boost, cmake

I have a C++ project to be included in an Android project. The project happily builds standalone, but when built with the Android SDK tools, it fails when trying to find Boost headers:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Android/SDK/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1753 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
```

The following variables are set both as CMake cache entries and environment variables:

```
BOOST_ROOT = ~/manual-software/boost/target
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = ~/manual-software/boost
```

I've narrowed it down to the following lines in FindBoost.cmake:

```
  # Look for a standard boost header file.
  find_path(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES         boost/config.hpp
    HINTS         ${_boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES ${_boost_PATH_SUFFIXES}
    )
```

Now the strange part is that I used the exact same CMake binary to build a) from the Android Studio terminal, and b) from the Android Studio build tools, and got two different results. The former building correctly, and the latter failing. I added the following message just below the `find_path` excerpt above:

```
  message(FATAL_ERROR "
    Boost_INCLUDE_DIR = ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
    _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = ${_boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS}
    _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = ${_boost_PATH_SUFFIXES}")
```

And now the output from a):

```
  Boost_INCLUDE_DIR = /home/chris/manual-software/boost
  _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = ~/manual-software/boost;~/manual-software/boost/target/include;~/manual-software/boost/target;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
  _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48
```

and b):

```
  Boost_INCLUDE_DIR = Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
  _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = ~/manual-software/boost;~/manual-software/boost/target/include;~/manual-software/boost/target;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
  _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;b
oost/boost_1_48
```

Why is `find_path` acting differently?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is down to CMake's cross-compilation safety features. CMake will not find paths that aren't in `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`, which in the case of Android cross-compilation, will be set to the relevant SDK path.

To use libraries from the host system (being careful that the library files are compatible with the target architecture), you must allow find to use both the system root and the find root path:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE BOTH)
```

In this case, only `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE` is necessary.